# Ender 3 needs Power Supply AND USB to work

Tags: troubleshooting, creality-ender-3, bltouch

I installed a BLTouch on my Ender 3 following this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sUlqrSq6LeY.

What I noticed too late was that when installing the BLTouch, I swapped the brown and red wires followed by connecting it to the mainboard.

Then I realized that the printer wouldn't turn on. After reading some of the comments, I swapped back the wire and I could see the BLTouch do its self-test.

However, it seems that I need to plug into the USB before the LCD + motors can work.

So is my mainboard fried? Or how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like I blew the regulator based on the comment in the Reddit post: https://www.reddit.com/r/ender3/comments/ao5m5b/ender_3_can_only_be_powered_on_by_psu_and_usb/